# Docker Desktop MultiContainer Not working 'Connection refused'

Tags: docker, containers

I'm new to playing with docker and run into what is properly a stupid issue.

I installed latest docker desktop on a Mac which is installed and running.

I've tried the multi container app on the Microsoft app

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/docker-multi-container?view=vsmac-2019

But keep getting 'Connection Refused' errors when trying to run it

Reading other answers, ive dismissed issue with my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dockerdemofrontend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockerdemofrontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerDemoFrontEnd/Dockerfile

  dockerdemoapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockerdemoapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerDemoAPI/Dockerfile
```

My DockerDemoAPI Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY DockerDemoAPI/DockerDemoAPI.csproj DockerDemoAPI/
RUN dotnet restore "DockerDemoAPI/DockerDemoAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerDemoAPI"
RUN dotnet build "DockerDemoAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerDemoAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerDemoAPI.dll"]
```

My DockerDemoFrontEnd DockerFile

```
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY DockerDemoFrontEnd/DockerDemoFrontEnd.csproj DockerDemoFrontEnd/
RUN dotnet restore "DockerDemoFrontEnd/DockerDemoFrontEnd.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerDemoFrontEnd"
RUN dotnet build "DockerDemoFrontEnd.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerDemoFrontEnd.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerDemoFrontEnd.dll"]
```

In my front end project
if I remove my http call and run the project

```
var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://DockerDemoApi/api/values/1");
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
ViewData["Message"] += " and " + await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

It runs fine, loads in safari and I can view the page.
If I put the HTTP back in I get the

```
HttpRequestException: Connection refused
```

Im lost how to resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: How about change `http://DockerDemoApi` to `http://dockerdemoapi`?

Comment: Hi, I tried that but made no difference